# Include for loop iteration number in list name

Tags: r, list, for-loop, nested-for-loop

this working for-loop creates a single output list of 10 dataframes each containing a random sample of two rows from my input dataframe.

```
dat <- iris
lst_2 <- list()  
  for (i in 1:10){
    dat_iter <- dat %>% group_by(Species) %>% #select v votes randomly
      slice_sample(n=2)
lst_2[[i]]<-dat_iter
  }
```

I would like to wrap that for loop in another for loop that creates two lists (instead of one, as above), each containing 10 dataframes with either two or three randomly-sampled rows from the input dataframe. In other words, one list will contain 10 dataframes each with two randomly sampled rows (as above) and the second list will contain 10 dataframes each with three randomly sampled rows.

I would like the names of the output lists to contain the number of rows their dataframes contain, e.g. lst_2 and lst_3.

I think I know how to code the outer loop:

```
dat <- iris
for (j in 2:3) {
CREATE LIST WITH NAME INCLUDING J
      for (i in 1:10){
        dat_iter <- dat %>% group_by(Species) %>% #select v votes randomly
          slice_sample(n=j)
    lst[[i]]<-dat_iter
      }
UPDATE LIST WITH RESULTS OF INNER LOOP
}
```

but I don't know how to:

1. initialize the output lists such that they're named with the iteration number of the outer loop (first capitalized line above) or
   (2) update the lists with the results of the inner loop (second capitalized line).

I am open to using another method if nested for loops aren't the best choice. My actual task involves an outer loop with 9 iterations (creates 9 lists) and an inner loop with 1000 iterations (each of the 9 lists contains 1000 dataframes, each dataframe contains 300,000 rows).

Thanks for any help! Mark

Comment: Check `?split()`

Comment: also check `?paste0`